# ipadOS downloads go directly to iCloud Drive folder, while iOS downloads stay on local device

Tags: ios, icloud, ipados

I recently downloaded a file to my iPhone and noticed that even though I have iCloud Drive turned on, the file did not automatically sync to iCloud Drive. Conversely, when I downloaded the same file on my iPad, the file was immediately uploaded to iCloud Drive. Why the discrepancy?

Comment: How was the file downloaded? Via Safari?

Comment: Yes, via Safari.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a setting for the Safari download location in the iOS/iPadOS Settings app.

Settings app > Safari > Downloads

Your iPhone is probably set to a local download folder on the iPhone, while your iPad is set toe the download folder within the iCloud "folder".

Can you check in the "Files" app if the downloaded file on your iPhone lives in the "On my iPhone" location?

Answer (score -1):

Apple broke ios 16-17 when you go to settings>safari>Downloads, now you can set your downloads to local but if you exit the settings app it force resets back to ivloud drive, so technically ios 16-17 is softlocked and impossible to actually save downloaded files from safari without them going directly to icloud, apple does this because they cant back door your device for your info, but if you store files/ or download files to their servers it allows them to sniff the data your accessing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That's simply wrong, at least in 17.3.1 downloads can easily be stored locally.